# How to reload/redisplay a form from within itself?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which I use as a modal dialog box for data entry.  When the user clicks on the OK button on the form, I want the button handler to perform data validations and if there is any error the form should reload/redisplay itself instead of returning to the caller.  Is this possible?

Caller code:

```
DatasetProperties propsWindow = new DatasetProperties();
if (propsWindows.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    return;
// Do other stuffs here
```

Form code:

```
public partial class DatasetProperties : Form
{
    // Constructor here

    // OK button handler
    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do data validations here
        if (errorsFound)
        {
            // How to reload/redisplay the form without return to caller?????
        }
     }
 }
```

Thanks for any help,

Comment: This is not really the way that Windows Forms work. Rather than reloading the form, you should simply change the settings/values of the relevant UI elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Form.DialogResult` inside your `DatasetProperties.btnOK_Click` method to **`DialogResult.None`**, this way your `DatasetProperties` form will not return to the caller Form ('close').

```
// OK button handler
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do data validations here
    if (errorsFound)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None;
        // How to reload/redisplay the form without return to caller?????
    }
 }
```

This way you can 'stay' in your `DatasetProperties` form as long as you have errors.
From the msdn, when the [DialogResult Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is set to `None` *Nothing is returned from the dialog box. This means that the modal dialog continues running.*

Comment: This is exactly the behavior I want.  Works beautifully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't let the user close the form without validation.

Use the FormClosing event.  Here's an example.  In lieu of the messageBox, include your validation code.  If it doesn't validate, e.cancel = true.

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel without saving any changes?", "Confirm Cancel", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) != DialogResult.Yes)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: I used:
    if (errorsFound) { e.Cancel = true; }
but the caller received DialogResult.OK instead of DialogResult.Cancel as expected.  What's wrong?

Comment: e.cancel is valid in FormClosing() event.   Not button-Click() event.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I may misunderstand your problem.   If you are validating in btnOK_Click(), all is good.   You don't need to do anything if it does not validate.  The form will just sit there.   After your if(errorsFound), you need an else (for when there are no errors).   When there are no errors, you need this.Close().

Answer (score 1):

as user1646737 mentioned you can use  FormClosing event like this:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do data validations here
    Close();
}
```

Event:

```
private void DatasetProperties_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
      e.Cancel = errorsFound;
  }
```

Comment: This works too.  But the solution from polkduran better suits my need.  Thanks.